# Defining enum for array in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

```
type": "array",
"items": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["MALE","FEMALE","WORKER"]
}
```

or

```
type": "array",
"items": {
    "type": "string",
},
"enum": ["MALE","FEMALE","WORKER"]
```

?

Nothing in the spec about this. The goal is of course to get swagger-ui to show the enum values.

Comment: Both validate in http://bigstickcarpet.com/swagger-parser/www/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first case is correct and these days swagger-ui generates a multiple-choise select of the enum values.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

It will depend on what you want to enum:

Each enum value MUST be of the described object type

- in first case a String
- in second one an Array of String

First syntax means *These are the possible values of the String in this array*

```
AnArray:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
    enum:
      - MALE
      - FEMALE
      - WORKER
```

This array can contain multiple String, but each String must have MALE, FEMALE or WORKER value.

[image: Rendering in Swagger UI: You have to put mouse pointer on the value to see enum]

Second one means *These are the possible values of this Array*

```
AnotherArray:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
  enum:
    - 
      - FEMALE
      - WORKER
    -
      - MALE
      - WORKER
```

Each enum value is therefore an array. In this example, this array can only have to possible value ["FEMALE","WORKER"] and ["MALE","WORKER"].

Unfortunately even if this syntax is valid, no enum values are shown in Swagger UI.

Comment: The first is what I want, but unfortunately only the second shows the enum values. (This is a request parameter definition). And in second case I have a flat structure, not array of arrays.

Comment: The second example is not an array of array but an array of string just like first example. The difference is on which level you put the enum (array vs array's item). I'm not sure to understand what you're seeking, could give some JSON example of this array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a filter restricting by enum, take a look below:

```
    - schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          enum: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
      in: query
      name: ContractStatus
      description: Status of the installment contract. 1- status-1 2- status-2 3- status-3 4- status-4 5- status-5
```