# How to make the user choose none or one or both from enum OpenApi 3.0

Tags: python, api, yaml, openapi

I have this list and I need the client to choose none or one or both of them and include it in the body post request with OpenApi 3.0:

```
[none, apple, banana, [apple, banana]]
```

this is what I did so far but not sure

````
 frut_type:
          type: string
          nullable: true
          enum:
            - null
            - apple
            - banana
            - enum: [ apple, banana ]
    enter code here
    ```
````

Comment: You probably need to define `fruit_type` as an "array of enums" - see [the 1st example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36888626/113116).

Comment: yeah that what i did and it's worked fine